# Grammar question, I did a test today my teacher said I got mistake

Tags: grammar

Original:

> No fish can live in the river because the river is so polluted.

=>The river is so polluted for fish to live in (true)

=>The river is so polluted for fish to live in it (false)

What problem to the second transformed sentence?

Comment: Neither of those sentences is correct.  Did your teacher say the first one is correct?  (Also, they should be called **correct/incorrect**, not *true/false*.)

Comment: _My teacher said I had made a mistake_. In fact, both 'transformed sentences' are wrong. It should be _The river is **too** polluted for fish to live in it_. You don't mean 'true or false', but 'correct or incorrect' or 'right or wrong'.

Comment: @KateBunting ironically, the inclusion or exclusion of "it" is not what makes this sentence correct or incorrect, either way is fine. The problem is with "so -> too" and "fishs -> fish"

Comment: Would you please correct your spelling and use a capital i for the pronoun I. Also, check the word fish. [I took  a test.]

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of faults, but your teacher is criticising one thing that is not a fault.

The teacher seems to criticise the prepostion at the end of the sentence.  But this is not always a mistake.

However, your rephrasing is incorrect.  You have misspelled "fish" (also you should use the plural form "fish" in this context and not "fishes").  Moreover the construction you should use is either:

> ... so polluted that fish cannot live in it.

or

> ... too polluted for fish to live in.

A construction like

> ... so polluted for fish to live in (it).

is incorrect with or without the word "it".

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence should be (keeping as close as possible to its original format):

*"The river is so polluted that fish cannot live in it."*

The first sentence is also wrong. Again, keeping as close as possible to its original format:

"The river is too polluted for fish to live in"

(Note that the plural of 'fish' is also 'fish'.)